# Hierarchial Parent Child Relationship .self join or union or both?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, parent-child, union

I have a table  in the following format:

```
sid   sname     pid      pname    ppid        pdetail

1.1   ABC       1.1.1    UVW      1.1.1.1      XSXXSX....
1.1   ABC       1.1.1    UVW      1.1.1.2      VDSVS...
1.1   ABC       1.1.2    DEF      1.1.2.1      DSVSDSD..
1.1   ABC       1.1.2    DEF      1.1.2.2      SVSDV...
1.2   XYZ       1.2.1    LMN      1.2.1.1      DFSDSD..
1.2   XYZ       1.2.2    GGF      1.2.2.1       CDSSS...
```

and so on...

I need to get the result in the following format..

```
 Id          Detail        Parentid     ppid        pdetail
 1.1         ABC             NULL      1.1.1.1     XSXXSX..
 1.1.1       UVW              1.1       ..          ...
 1.1.1       UVW              1.1        ..           ..
 1.1.2       DEF              1.1        ..           ..
 1.1.2       DEF              1.1
  1.2        LMN              NULL
 1.2.1       LMN              1.2
 1.2.2       GGF              1.2
```

I have no idea how to proceed...any help would be great on how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `self join`, because all the informations you want about the parent are already available. All you have to do is a `union`:

```
select  *
from    (
            select  pid as Id, pname as Detail, sid as ParentId, ppid, pdetail
            from    table
            union all
            select  sid, sname, null, ppid, pdetail
            from table
        )
order by Id
```

Comment: hey , the query is working great in terms of result..only the ordering seems to be little problem..i'm getting the result in the following order.

Comment: I'm getting 1.1.1  1.1.1 1.1.2 1.1.2 first and then 1.1...whereas it should be the other way round..any solution for that?

Comment: Try with this: `order by rpad(Id, 5, '.0')`